# Conjecture:$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^3(x)\sin(3\pi x)}{x^4} J_0(x)^2\text{d}x \overset{?}{=} \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, closed-form, conjectures

I found
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^3(x)\sin(3\pi x)}{x^4} J_0(x)^2\text{d}x=1.570796...
\overset{?}{=} \frac{\pi}{2}$$
Where $J_0(x)$ is the 0th Bessel functions of the first kind.
I try to use the following identity,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} J_0(x)e^{-i\omega x}\text{d}x
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\omega^2} }$$
And
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(x)e^{i\omega x}\text{d}x
=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x)G(\omega-x)\text{d}x$$
Where $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)e^{-itx}\text{d}t,
G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)e^{-itx}\text{d}t$.
But the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} J_0(x)^2e^{i\omega x}\text{d}x$ involves $K(k)$(Complete elliptic integral of the first kind).So it's not a good way to prove it.
Now I don't have any idea to prove it. Are there any hints? Or what techniques should I use?

Comment: [How to ask a good question ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/)

Comment: What is $J_0$? Please provide more context to the question, else there is a good danger for many downvotes, and/or for closing it for many reasons of not meeting the standards of the site. Please insert e.g. what did you try, numerical support, which is the source, why should this integral be important, related integrals with known values (if there are some), etc. ... If you have a good question, you still have to work to have a good question accepted on this site, the effort will always be honoured...

Answer (score 10):

This integral is sort of like a [Borwein integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral).

The function $$f(z) = \sin^{3}(z) e^{iaz} J_{0}(z)^{2}$$ is entire.

And as $|z| \to \infty$,the Bessel function of the first kind of order zero has the [asymptotic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms)$$J_{0}(z) \sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}} \cos \left(z-\frac{\pi}{4} \right) , \quad |\arg(z)| < \pi, $$ which means that $|f(z)|$ is bounded in the upper half of the complex plane if $a \ge 5$.

(If $ a<5$, $|f(z)|$ will grow exponentially as $\Im(z) \to +\infty$. And  if $  a > -5$, $|f(z)|$ will grow exponentially as $\Im(z) \to - \infty$.)

Therefore, if $a \ge 5$, we can integrate the function $$g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z^{4}}$$ around an  infinitely large semicircular contour in the upper half-plane that is indented at the origin, apply the estimation lemma,  and conclude that $$ \operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \, \mathrm dx- i \pi \operatorname{Res} \left[g(z), 0 \right] =0, $$ where $$\operatorname{Res} \left[g(z), 0 \right] = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\sin^{3}(z)}{z^{3}} \, e^{iaz} J_{0}(z)^{2}= 1(1)(1) =1. $$

Equating the imaginary parts on both sides of the equation, we get $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{3}(x) \sin(ax) J_{0}(x)^{2}}{x^{4}} \, \mathrm dx = \pi \, , \quad a \ge 5.$$

Since the integrand is even, it follows that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{3}(x) \sin(ax) J_{0}(x)^{2}}{x^{4}} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \, , \quad a \ge 5. $$

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer.But if $a<5$,have some good expressions?